# Turn off notifications

Tags: android, notifications, wifi

I'm a freshman in Android developing. I'm interested in how can I turn on, for example, wifi, but without any notifications sent? I mean, when I turn on the wifi module, I receive a standard notification and I want to turn them off using code. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Your question is too broad and may be off-topic.

Comment: Okey, I'll try to rephrase is. Is there any way to turn off default notifications in code in application?

Comment: No, you cannot turn off system notifications.